# Can kvass be made without bread?

Tags: drinks, fermentation

While searching for kvass recipes some of them mentioned that kvass can be made with rye flour or malt and since I can't find 100% rye breads where I live making them just for kvass would be too expensive.My question is - can kvass be made without bread and if it can't then can bread mush be reused to make more kvass (or use kvass to make more of it) instead of baking another bread?Also in a country near mine one company makes this drink and on the label it says that main ingredients are wheat and rye malt.

Comment: Yes, you can make it with rye flour / malt. Rye bread (and often "special buns" made explicitly for kvass) was a method to have the necessary material at hand at your convenience. You shouldn't re-use any bread mush, because it's food for the yeast and "used up" after fermentation.

Comment: So how do you make it using flour/malt?

Comment: Just use any recipe from the internet. My experience is too limited or I would have written a comprehensive answer.

Comment: Well that's the problem, I found only 1 but there are no comments so i have no idea if it will work. http://www.ruscuisine.com/recipes/beverages-and-drinks/n--381/

Comment: @user3711671: Giving it a try is the only way to find out, it's one of the fun parts of cooking :) Make a small batch, see what happens :)

Answer (score 3):

Kvass can be made without bread, e.g. "beet kvass" can be gotten going with minced raw beet root (fill jar between 1/4 and 1/3 full), a 3% saline solution (or thereabouts?), and a dollop of sourdough starter. I believe other starters (e.g. from milk products) can also be used, but I haven't dabbled with those. Mine bubbles for two to possibly three days, though mold may be a problem, so you'll want to monitor for that, figure out a reasonable upper limit, and strain and consume or find a refrigerator somewhere to stash the kvass in.

Fresh ginger root also makes for a nice addition, or spices to taste, or carrots...